# using metpy package to find the moist_static_energy of different variables of temeparture, height and specific himifty

Tags: python, metpy

Code:

```
mi =[]
for T in np.array(df_use['TEMP']):
    for z in np.array(df_use['HGHT']):
        for q in qv:
            moist_stat_energy = moist_static_energy(z* units.meters,T* units.degC, q * units('g/kg'))
            moist.append(mi)
```

Comment: That code looks ok. What problem are you having?

Comment: the range of values gotten is more than the required range needed

Comment: What range of values do you need? That's not at all clear from the question/code above.